# Missing and not working glob.c on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, glob

Some app requires glob.c for path routines though it's missing in android ndk 9. I've tried ported https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/source/browse/tesseract-android-tools/jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/#com_googlecode_tesseract_android%2Fglibc and it's not working. I mean for:

```
const char *tmp = "/data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.myapp/sdk/";
glob(tmp, GLOB_MARK, 0, &glob_results);
fprintf(stderr, "gl_pathc = %i\n", glob_results.gl_pathc);
```

it prints glob_results.gl_pathc = 0 though the folder exists:

```
MBA-Anton:platform-tools asmirnov$ ./adb shell ls /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.myapp/sdk/
binutils-compact#2.23#1
cppcheck#1.64a#1
gcc#4.8#2
libclang#3.3#1
libcloog#0.18.0#1
libgcc-compact-dev#4.8#1
libgmp#5.0.5#1
libisl#0.11.1#1
libmpc#1.0.1#1
libmpfr#3.1.1#1
libstdc++-compact-dev#4.8#1
ndk-sysroot-16#r9c#1
```

Is there any working glob.c or what is the problem with this one?

UPDATE: i've also tried with err function but it's not invoked:

```
int glob_error(const char *message, int error) {
    std::cout << "glob error: " << message << "\n";
    return 1;
}

// ...
glob(tmp, GLOB_MARK, &glob_error, &glob_results);
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, I struggle the same, but I used another glob.c and glob.h from a different source and the problem is fixed. The reason why the code you used must fail is because the author has taken out collate functionality, but the one I am referring has it. solving my problem, I hope it would help someone. The source below doesn't need you to compile the collate.c file,since the author has copied the necessary function into the glob.c.

https://github.com/danstowell/GlastoCollider-Android/tree/master/jni/Source/libc